# Complete decimal places of a float

Tags: python

How do I store a floating number with its complete decimal places in Python 2.7?

For example:

```
x = 1.0/3
```

Then `x` should be `0.333...` but Python stores to the 15th decimal place only (if I am not wrong).

However, I want to store `0.33333` in such a way that the decimal places never end (the entire decimal places are preserved).

Comment: A computer cannot "store" an infinitely long succession of "0.333..." it must truncate at some point. Your best bet would be to use the `fractions` module to preserve resolution of the numbers.

Comment: 1/3 results in a decimal that never ends. Storing all the decimal figures is just not possible. Ask a real question.

Comment: This is documented in the python docs: [Floating Point Arithmetic 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 3):

There will *always* be numbers that you cannot represent in anything less than infinite storage, if you insist on using non-symbolic encoding schemes.

For your example, `1/3`, you cannot represent it as `0.3333...` simply because the threes never end. For that particular example, you could use rational schemes like a fraction (a number with numerator and denominator).

However, that won't help with irrationals like the square root of two, or π. Symbolic encodings leave the number in its original form rather than trying to force it to `1.414` ir `3.14159` and systems using those encodings generally understand how to manipulate those symbols.

For example, [plug `e(i×pi)` into Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28i*pi%29&lk=4&num=2&lk=4&num=2) and you get `-1`.

If you insist on, or are restricted to, non-symbolic schemes, you'll just have to accept that there will be numbers you can't represent exactly. The "solution" is to have enough precision that the errors won't accumulate to the point where they're visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module. It does not have floating-point round off errors due to the inexactness of binary representations, and you can set the precision to as large as you need (theoretically infinity).

Comment: Although the decimal module is the answer given in the docs it still will not represent precision to infinity (0.1 == `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`). It will only represent infinity in the extended sets (such as divide by zero) as literally 'Infinity' or 'Inf' - so still is not an answer to the OPs question.

Comment: @JGreenwell You can set the precision to as many digits as needed with decimal (theoretically if the size of a variable wasn't restricted by physical space, you could have an infinite number of digits). Division by zero produces a value of infinity, which is not the same thing as a precision of infinity digits.

Comment: "It does not have floating-point round off errors due to the inexactness of binary representations" - but it has floating-point rounding errors due to the inexactness of decimal representations.

Comment: Actually, that was my point exactly. The OP wanted to know how to "store a floating point number with its complete decimal places" and the answer is you can't because of the limitation inherent in decimal representations. The phrasing used ("as large as you need (theoretically infinity)") could be misconstrued as saying "as large as infinity". One still cannot represent 1.3 repeating without symbolic methods or fractions (in this case).

Answer (score -2):

You shoul use function [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> x = 1.0/3
>>> x
0.3333333333333333
>>> y = round(x, 5)
>>> y
0.33333
```

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what is being asked.